# Ordenar pelo valor do ENUM MySql

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, codeigniter, enums

tenho uma duvida e como não encontrei nada na internet decidi perguntar a vocês, bom, tenho uma tabela MySql e essa tabela contem um campo ENUM que pode ser 'sim' ou 'nao', gostaria de saber se é possível ordenar os resultados por esses valores, tipo assim

```
SELECT * FROM tabela ORDER BY tabela.coluna = 'nao'
```

para que os valores apresentados como não sejam apresentados primeiro, o problema é que não consigo fazer isso funcionar com o codeigniter, o que faço?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/enum.html#enum-sorting):

> Valores ENUM são classificadas com base em seus índices, que dependem
>   da ordem em que os membros de enumeração foram listados na
>   especificação da coluna. Por exemplo, 'nao' antes de 'sim' para
>   ENUM('nao', 'sim'). Strings nullas ou vazias vêm antes de todos os
>   outros valores de enumeração.

Para evitar problemas com a ordenação de colunas ENUM, utilize:

1. Declare a lista ENUM em ordem alfabética.
2. Certifique-se de que a coluna é classificada em ordem alfabética e não por número de índice codificando `ORDER BY CAST (coluna AS CHAR)` ou `ORDER BY CONCAT (coluna)`.

Tente utilizar :

`ORDER BY CAST(tabela.coluna AS CHAR)`

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou muito